# how to make ternary operator on onPressed

Tags: flutter, if-statement, button, navigation, dialog

I'm running a similar code to the code below

showPage is a bool. results is a string.

Actions on the page itself will decide the bool status and the string.

The onPressed below is the bottom button on the page I'm at. For the user to navigate.

I would like the onPressed to pop up a different dialog depending on the status of showPage, and print the results.

Code as follows:

```
onPressed: showPage? ()
{ShowDialogA(context:context); print(results);}
:{ShowDialogB(context:context); print(results);},
```

But I'm getting an error the first semi colon after ShowDialogB: 'expected to find }'
Any thoughts why?

And if I remove the semi colon and do the following:

```
onPressed: showPage? ()
{ShowDialogA(context:context); print(results);}
:ShowDialogB(context:context),
```

I get the error:  type 'Future' is not a subtype of type '(() => void)?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got error because on else command you forgot to put ().
Try this:

```
onPressed: showPage
    ? () {
        ShowDialogA(context:context); print(results);
      }
    : () {
        ShowDialogB(context:context); print(results);
      },
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Reading `{ShowDialogB(context:context); print(results);}` as the else-ternary-result happens because the `onPressed` property requires a function, and in the code you showed, only the if-ternary-result (`(){ShowDialogA(context:context); print(results);}`) is a proper function. I believe you simply forgot two parentheses `()` before `{ShowDialogB(context:context); print(results);}`, so you should replace it by `(){ShowDialogB(context:context); print(results);}`

As for your ternary syntax, don't worry about it because it is correct! Simply correct your function as follows:

```
onPressed: showPage ? () {
    ShowDialogA(context:context);
    print(results);
} : () {
    ShowDialogB(context:context);
    print(results);
},
```

And let me know if it solved your problem!

Comment: hey Raxx, thanks for your explanation regarding the future vs function. Plugged in the code, theres no error! 
But when I hit the final button, nothing happens, nothing is printed in the terminal, the dialog doesn't pop up. 

Comment: Sorry, put a small mistake on my answer too! But yeah, simply add the parentheses ;)

Comment: no worries bro! All good! Thank you so much!